# Understanding Spring redirects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

I encountered a small problem in my Spring application. I am using Spring Security to handle logins and logouts. It works very fine. My question is however about redirects in Spring. What I am talking about: By default, the Spring Security is configured in the way, that after successful logout, it redirects user to `/login?logout` which works totally fine, same for `/login?error`.

I am trying to implement a simple "Enter your email here to reset your password". The page resides at `/resetPassword`. Here is the relevant part of the template:

```
<form name="f" th:action="@{/resetPassword}" method="post" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Login email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Reset password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my method that handles that looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/resetPassword")
fun resetPasswordForEmail(@RequestParam("email") email: String): String {
    userFacade.resetPassword(email)
    return "redirect:/login?reset"
}
```

A method gets called, everything is fine, **but**: in the browser, I am not being redirected to `/login?reset` but I was redirected even further, more specifically back to `/login`. I can see that in developer tools in Chrome.

However, I do not know why that's happening. I also tried with `RedirectAttributes`, with returning `RedirectView`, but same result all the time.

Can anyone give me something to catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loggedin so Spring security redirect you to the login.
You must configure it with ROLE_ANONYMOUS to allow access to resetpassword page.

Comment: I got in my security config this:
`.antMatchers("/resetPassword")?.permitAll()?.loginPage("/login")?.successForwardUrl("/home")?.permitAll()`.
Isn't this sufficient? If not, could you please extend your answer with an explanation?

Comment: you reach /resetPassword then your controller send back to the browser "OK, now go to /login?reset" then  you backend check id "/login?reset" can be reached otherwise take you to login page

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It goes to `login?reset` after it finishes some work. I'm sorry, but I still don't get what's wrong with that. I guess it should be okay to go to `/login?reset`, because login page is set as `permitAll()`, isn't it? If not, then how is it possible that `/login?error` and `/login?logout` work fine (when I type address manually to the browser) @ivan.rosina

Comment: Okay, it worked. Could you please provide an explanation please? I accept this answer then.

Comment: redirect is a message to the browser to call another page (in this case login?reset)  so, the NEW call is checked from SpringSecurity and, it's still anonymous, so Spring security take you to the login page. This does not happen if you add login?reset in anonymous "list"